# Ubuntu partition has slower network speeds than Windows one

Tags: networking, wireless, 15.10, realtek

We have Verizon FiOS, and are slated to get 75/75, according to our plan. I understand that we may not always get these numbers, but between Windows and Xubuntu there is a huge discrepancy.

Also, FWIW, when I log into Xubuntu, the Wifi connects, but does not work initially. I need to disconnect the Wifi then reconnect for it to actually work. And when I do this, I get error popups saying there was a system issue, and whether I'd like to report. (Presumably about the network manager stalling.)

[**UPDATED** Snapshot of my wireless-info](https://gist.github.com/onebree/f76709abe5b35576bb47cfe6ac643b0e)

---

### Speedtest.net results

- Windows 10 home (first try)

  - [2.4 GHz: 55.78 / 66.80](http://beta.speedtest.net/result/5235443074)
  - [5.0 GHz: 79.45 / 89.18](http://beta.speedtest.net/result/5235446193)
- Xubuntu 15.10 (first)

  - [2.4 GHz: 11.71 / 0.84](http://beta.speedtest.net/result/5235460187)
  - 5.0 GHz: Could not connect
- Windows (second)

  - [2.4 GHz: 60.46 / 69.70](http://beta.speedtest.net/result/5235500034)
  - [5.0 GHz: 83.55 / 75.49](http://beta.speedtest.net/result/5235495219)
- Xubuntu (second)

  - [2.4 GHz: 13.45 / 0.82](http://beta.speedtest.net/result/5235539407)
  - 5.0 GHz: Could not connect

### Output from `sudo lspci`

```
03:00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8821AE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
04:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 0c)
```

---

### More updates

- Another FWIW, I've ran `apt-get update` a few times throughout today. Each time, only 1000+ kb were downloaded in 1.5 minutes.
- tx power set to max (20), no power save, kernel 4.2
- At this point, my workflow *is* being affected. I tried to upload a 2.1 MB PNG file to a Github issue comment, but it failed after 3 minutes of waiting. During this time, *I could not visit other webpages -- they stalled*.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/38185/discussion-on-question-by-onebree-ubuntu-partition-has-slower-network-speeds-tha).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After a couple weeks of research, I've found that my wireless card is simply not supported. There are plenty of other questions on AskUbuntu about the RTL8821AE card, or even just RealTek.

Here is what I found *did not* help:

- No difference: Disabling BlueTooth or IPv6
- No difference: Using the [unofficial drivers from Github](https://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new)
- Unavailable: official drivers from RealTek for RTL88xx series

Since this was disrupting my workflow *far too much*, I decided to purchase the following item. I like this option, because I can utilize dual-band wifi (see stats in question).

[NETGEAR Universal N600 Dual Band Wi-Fi to Ethernet Adapter](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B005N6XBDO)

While I did not try them, other options include:

- Use a USB Wifi Adapter (best for laptops or micro PCs)
- Install a new wireless card (best for the regular desktop)

As mentioned in the question, I was getting *poor* speeds on Ubuntu, compared to Windows. Now, on the 5.0 GHz network (through adapter), I get 80/80 on both Windows, Ubuntu 15.10, *and* Ubuntu 16.04.

Answer (score -1):

Debian supports your driver but the firmware is non-free. (I know this is Ubuntu, but it's built on Debian and can use its packages.)

Execute the following:

```
sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Add the following line to the file:

```
deb http://httpredir.debian.org/debian/ jessie main contrib non-free
```

Install the Debain package firmware:

```
sudo apt-get update && apt-get install firmware-realtek
```

---

**UPDATE**: Let me know if this works.

Make a temp directory (TARGET_DIR) for now-uncompiled package:

```
dpkg-deb -x linux-firmware_1.149.3_all.deb TARGET_DIR
```

Edit the Debian/control file. The most important part of any source package, it holds the dependencies.

```
dpkg-deb --control linux-firmware_1.149.3_all.deb TARGET_DIR/DEBIAN
```

Edit the `depends` field, and add `firmware-realtek_0.43_all.deb`. Then save your changes and repack

```
nano TEMP_DIR/DEBIAN/control
```

Install package:

```
dpkg -b TEMP_DIR newdriver.deb
sudo dpkg -i newdriver.deb
```

Install `firmware-realtek`

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Comment: (1) The second part of the command was not tied to `sudo`.

Comment: oh, yeah you'll need two sudos

Comment: (2) I got the following error message => https://gist.github.com/onebree/942d2bb838edde43b03da387477986e3

Comment: crapppppp. I'll need a bit to look into it. Looks like a dependency hell.

Comment: I just searched for `realtek`, and found the following:  https://gist.github.com/onebree/1096d29fc9cc14d1687cc42981f6cfd9

Comment: I also want to note, that in my repos, I do not have Canonical/Partners checked in the settings. Should I enable them?

Comment: I think you need to remove that firmware first.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/38147/discussion-between-onebree-and-nebulon).

Comment: I think you'll have to remove /lib/firmware/RTL8192E/main.img for it to work. I guess it's the shitty free version of the driver.