# Ubuntu 16.04 WiFi connection issue

Tags: wireless, connection

Sorry if this is dumb, I'm new to Ubuntu and just jumped in.
My issue is the my WiFi will connect fine, but after a few minutes it will stop working, but still say it's connected fine. I can temporarily fix this by disconnecting and reconnecting, but it will occur again.
I'm not sure if I need some sort of driver or software, so if anyone can answer or anything it's greatly appreciated.

Edit:

```
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8821AE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [10ec:8821]

   Subsystem: XAVi Technologies Corp. RTL8821AE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [1b9a:2482]

   Kernel driver in use: rtl8821ae

   Kernel modules: rtl8821ae
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of  `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3` terminal command. This will give the information needed about your specific WiFi device. Also make sure to set the recommended wireless encryption settings, WPA2-AES, at your router. Avoid any WPA/WPA2 mixed mode and/or TKIP.

Comment: @MichaelBay edited my question with that info

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Wireless disconnect issues Ubuntu 16.04 with RTL8821ae](https://askubuntu.com/questions/797213/wireless-disconnect-issues-ubuntu-16-04-with-rtl8821ae) Yes, your device need tweaks, the default driver installed by Ubuntu isn't the best.

Comment: @MichaelBay I don't see a valid answer for that question

Comment: @Jeremy31 Isn't it the same device, same Ubuntu release and same problem? Shouldn't at least the `ant_sel` work? From all that I've read regarding this chipset that seems to be the main issue.

Comment: @MichaelBay the one answer was downvoted and the other one didn't work for the asker.  It is the same device

Comment: @Jeremy31 Ok, flag retracted but regardless of that particular case - and my choice of dupe was unfortunate indeed - when I looked at the upvoted answer it made sense and was consisted why what I've been reading about this chipset with Ubuntu, specifically the issue with the single antenna certain manufacturers ship it with that is correctly detected by the Windows driver but not with the Linux driver.

Comment: @MichaelBay the single antenna issue seems to be limited to HP laptops with RTL8723be chipsets

Comment: @MichaelBay I think that post may have helped me figure out my issue, so thank you very much