# Wifi Driver ubuntu 16.04

Tags: drivers, wireless

I´m not a computer professional, more an amateur.
I have Ubuntu, and I dont have WiFi connecton. Somehow i figured out I need a Driver, but i searched all over the internet an i just can not find anything that works. I connected with my ethernet cable and I tried to search on additional drivers but there is nothing. 
I have a Lenovo y700 with AMD processor and graphics.

```
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8821AE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [10ec:8821]
```

Best regards

Comment: Let's start by identifying your wireless device. Please open a terminal Ctrl+Alt+t and run and post: `lspci -nnk | grep 0280` Welcome to askubuntu.

Comment: 02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8821AE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [10ec:8821]

Comment: Related: http://askubuntu.com/questions/822298/network-issues-on-16-04-with-rtl8821ae