# WiFi can’t work in Ubuntu 18.04 with RTL8821AE

Tags: networking, wireless, internet, 18.04

The WiFi connection cant work in my ubnutu 18,04 LTS, so anyone can help

[my wifi info script output](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/QHXvh3rP94/)

Comment: Please clone and run this script to display [wireless info](https://github.com/UbuntuForums/wireless-info.git)

Comment: I run this script so what can I do in the next step

Comment: Please save the result in http://paste.ubuntu.com/ and paste that link here.

Comment: this is the output file : https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/pV2n4T7PVG/

Comment: You need to include `wireless-info.txt`.

Comment: I cant  understand  you, what do you mean by this

Comment: we need the output of the script. You ran the script, it saved a file on your system. We need to see the text of that file. Wireless problems are hardware specific. There is no way we can answer questions about them without details of your hardware and software. The script gathers this information into a text file.

Comment: When you run `./wireless-info` script, the result is stored in `wireless-info.txt` file, you should save it in paste.ubuntu.com and paste the link here.

Comment: This is the  output file https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/QHXvh3rP94/

Comment: @user Try this [answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/872313/wireless-issues-on-16-04-with-rtl8821ae-asus-e202s)